# Referencing requirejs optimized typescript classes

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I am switing to using AMD compilation rather than typescript internal modules.

I have a project full of typescript classes and interfaces that I have successfully optimized into a requirejs file full of requirejs defines.

for example

class A {
     ...
   }
   export A;

Other classes reference the file and import the class fine.

In another project I pull in the R.js optimized file using bower and reference it in require_config.js and load the file ok.

Within this other project I want Class B to reference class A but class B is not in the file path.

What do I need to do? I guess I need to generate d.ts files that I reference in Class B but how do I do import ClassA = require("ClassA") when ClassA is not in the file path of the second project.

James

Comment: I don't see where your example shows that you're using requireJS. Anyway you should be able to access classB using its relative path from the site root.

Comment: if I compiled Class A with -m AMD I would get a js file that looked like this:define(["require", "exports", dependencies], function (require, exports, dependencies) {
    return ClassA
});

Comment: `but class B is not in the file path` ... class A or B?

Comment: sorry my mistake. I edited the question - Class B does not have Class A in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second project can use a definition file `.d.ts`:

```
// ---------- projectA.d.ts ----------
declare module "projectA" {
    export class A {
        // ...
    }
}

// ---------- ClassB.ts ----------
import projectA = require("projectA"); // Use the definition in projectA.d.ts
var a = new projectA.A();
```

See the section "Ambient External Modules" [in the Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries).

You can automatically generate a single definition file bundle from your projectA using [dts-generator](https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator).

Comment: what I find puzzling about this is that when you build Class A for use with requirejs, you do not use the key word module (which is used by the internal
module system). if you compile Class A with the -d flag, you get a ClassA.d.ts but it does not have a module declaration like the one you describe. 
Is there any way that you can get the compiler to output a d.ts with a module declaration like your file from your own sources. Is the only way to do this is to use 
the module key word (i.e. only when you are using the typescript internal module system?

Comment: AFAIK, no, you can't. But you can generate a file `.d.ts` then modify it to add `declare module` and `export`.

Comment: Beware quotes. With quotes: `declare module "projectA"` here `"projectA"` is an external module. Without quotes: `declare module ProjectA` here `ProjectA` is an internal module (i.e. a namespace).

Comment: I updated the answer to link to a project that can automatically generate d.ts bundles.

Comment: i created the ambient external module and added import projectA = require("projectA");. The code generated looked like this define(["require", "exports", "projectA"], function (require, exports, projectA) {
} and this correctlly pulled in the requirejs optimized file. However when I did var a = new projectA.A(), this failed because projectA was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment that projectA was undefined when I did var a = new projectA.A(), I discovered that the reason for this lay in the way that the R.js optimized file (projectA.js) has been built - it needed an insertRequire added to the R.js build. This caused a require["projectA"] to be called when projectA was loaded and projectA was instantiated properly.

There are a quite a few moving parts here. It is a pity that typescript external modules and internal modules work so differently. Depending on the syntax declare module "SomeModuleName" and declare module SomeModuleName to distinguish via use of quotes between external and internal modules is confusing.

It would be great if the syntax was the same and the compiler -m flag handled all the underlying detail.